Question about the coordinate system on the manifold
Given an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ and a homeomorphism $\phi:U\subset M\rightarrow V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ from a patch on the manifold $U\subset M$, then we can parametrize a point $p\in U$ via the inverse map $\phi^{-1}:V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow U\subset M$?
More explicitly, if $\phi (p)=(x^{1},\ldots,x^{n})$ are the coordinates labelling $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then is it correct to say that one can describe a point in a given patch on the manifold directly via its parametrization with respect to its coordinates, i.e.
$$p=(\phi^{-1}\circ\phi)(p)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(p))=\phi^{-1}(x^{1},\ldots,x^{n})=(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})$$
where $(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})$ is the local parametrization of $p$ on $M$, and $u^{i}=u^{i}(x^{1},\ldots,x^{n})$ are functions whose domain is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

If I have understand this notion of parametrization correctly, then is the following discussion correct? If we take the example of a 2-sphere $S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then is the 2-tuple $(\theta,\phi)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ the coordinates of a point on the manifold (with the mapping defined by $p\mapsto (\theta,\phi)$) and its corresponding local parametrization on the manifold, $(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta))\in S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (with the inverse mapping defined by $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto (\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta))$) ?

My doubt may be silly but I am confused so I am asking as we see that the points on the sphere surface can be represented by $(x,y,z)$ which in the above example taken in the spherical coordinate right so we use the coordinate map $\phi$ and map it to the two dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^2$ which we have taken as $(\theta,\phi)$ right so se see we are switching from $3$ points on the sphere to $2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ now when we take inverse we get back those $3$ points on the sphere so we will switch back from $2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $3$ points on the sphere right and here is my doubt as we see in the definition we have a point $p$ on the manifold $M$ as $\phi(p)=(x^1,...,x^n)$ which is $n$ points and while taking the inverse we have $(u^1,...,u^n)$ which is again $n$ points only how? I mean in our example it is not same there it is $3$ to $2$ and $2$ to $3$ but why in the definition it is $n$ from both sides?

I don't understand what your $u^i$ are. $M$ is an abstract space whose elements don't necessarily have their own natural coordinate system. If $\phi(p)=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then $\phi^{-1}((x_1,\dots,x_n))$ is just $p$.

$p=\phi^{-1}(x^1,\cdots,x^n)$ is sensible. $(u^1,\cdots,u^n)$ does not have sense though; this suggests $\phi^{-1}$ itself has 'components', which it doesn't really. The abstract $n$-manifold does not itself have $n$-coordinates, these only make sense when you're working in a chart (which is somewhere else.. not on the manifold). You already have the $x^i$, but you haven't defined the $u^i$ and I don't think this is generally a sensible concept. What new information do you need? The $x^i$ already do a job of parametrising.
Let's take your $S^2$ example. This is canonically embedded in $\Bbb R^3$, and there is a possible chart (which omits a great semicircle connecting North and South) $\phi:U:=S^2\setminus\{x\ge 0,y=0\}\to(0,2\pi)\times(0,\pi)=:V$ defined - with $\psi=\phi^{-1}$ - by $\psi(\phi,\theta)=(\cos\phi\sin\theta,\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$. Here, your "$x^i$" would correspond to "$\phi,\theta$" but what are the $u^i$ supposed to be? One option is to take the compositions $\pi_i\circ\iota\circ\psi$, where $\pi_i$ are the canonical coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$ and $\iota:S^2\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^3$. You've noticed we have three, in this case, rather than two. This isn't a problem. The definition of manifold has 'local coordinates' coming from charts, coming from the open $V=\phi(U)$ (in your notation); there is absolutely no requirement to have anything else. The 'other' coordinates on $S^2$ come from a choice of embedding of $S^2$ into a Euclidean space; by the Whitney embedding theorem, this is essentially always possible. However this is (i) non-canonical and (ii) you don't get to embed it (always) into Euclidean space of the same dimension. For example, it is impossible to embed $S^2\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^2$. I won't prove that here, but this certainly explains why I cannot have two global coordinate functions $u^1,u^2:S^2\to\Bbb R$ describing all points.
The only parametrisation you can do is to use the $x^i$ functions (in your notation). One thing worth noting is that this really, hugely depends on the choice of chart. Given an abstract $3$-manifold $M$, there is absolutely no sense in saying $p=(1,2,3)$, where $p\in M$. I would need to say $p\in U\cong V\subset\Bbb R^n$ and under this choice of chart, $p$ corresponds to $(1,2,3)$. Using a different chart, $(1,2,3)$ could describe a completely different point on the manifold!

if we see wrt the sphere so in this case we will have $(u^1,u^2,u^3)=(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta))$ right? and in this case, we will have $(\theta,\phi)=(x^1,x^2)$. so we have coordinate chart map as $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto (\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta))$ so this we are doing for an open subset $U of S^2$ now doubt is we take the inverse of this map we will get the point on the sphere(our manifold) so why in the abstract case have both $(u^1,..,u^n)$ and $(x^1,..,x^n)$ why in both the index is same "n hope I am able to express my doubt

I know you mean on the abstract manifold there is no coordinate but that definition should also applicable on the sphere case right? in the sphere case as we see that $p=(1,2,3)$ and by coordinate chart map we map it to $\phi(p)=(a,b) say$ and inverse map gives us from $\phi(p)=(a,b)$ to $p=(1,2,3)$ so here we are going from $(u^1,u^2,u^3)--->(x^1,x^2)$ and from $(x^1,x^2)--->(u^1,u^2,u^3)$ as we see here "n" is not same

@Andyale The point I'm making and the commenter made is that the $u^i$ don't really make sense in general. The fact that $S^2$ is naturally viewed in $\Bbb R^3$, where other coordinates are available, is a quirk. It is coincidence. If I define $S^2$ differently, then the $u^i$ coordinates wouldn't make any sense at all. In particular, there is no sense in which the $u^i$ are associated to dimension. The $3$ and $2$ thing is not a problem; $S^2$ is a $2$-manifold, but you have embedded it into $\Bbb R^3$, not $\Bbb R^2$.

You cannot define the $u^i$ directly from the definition of a chart and atlas on a manifold
